# texlive and /usr/local vs /usr/share

Tags: texlive

I installed a full texlive today. As usual, this produced two directories:

1. /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex,
   and
2. /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex

Why there's so much duplication I have no idea. But that's another issue.

The poemscol.sty file I planned to use appears in 1) but not in 2). So when I run texmaker, it produces an error that the poemscol.sty file cannot be found, since texmaker looks for the file in directory 2).

I'm not sure what to make of this. It is a problem for the package provider, or can I simply create the necessary sub-dir in 2) and copy the *.sty file to it?

Thanks!

Comment: What commands did you use to install TeX Live?

Comment: I used the directions found in "Installing Texlive over the Internet" that ctan suggests. Basically download a tar.gz file, unpacked it, and then did sudo ./install-tl recommended in the ctan "quick installation instructions.. No obvious problems during the install.

Comment: Have a look on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ as it's answerdthere multiple times already...